# How do you calculate the power limits and heat dissipation of microstrip filters on a PCB?

Tags: power, pcb-design, rf, filter, microstrip

We are designing a microstrip diplexer with a high-pass and low-pass filter.  What are the power-limiting factors of such a design?

The low-pass is a T configuration with two spiral inductors and a capacitor made from square copper on two different layers of the PCB, where the lower layer of the cap is grounded.  The high-pass is a Pi of similar construction but the capacitor is the pass-through and the spiral inductors are grounded.

- Would the low-pass be limited by the current carrying capacity of the microstrip through the spiral inductors?  Any other factors?
- How is the high-pass limited?  I am guessing that it is limited by heat dissipation caused by ESR between the capacitor plates. If so, then given a \$ E_r \$ dielectric constant, a square capacitor surface area, and the distance between plates, is it possible to calculate the ESR?
- Other considerations?

Comment: Saturn PCB design .exe will compute this for you. Choose low temp rise of 30’C or less by thickness of Cu many consider Au plating if high current.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, perhaps it should be obvious, but which tab of Saturn PCB Design will compute temperature rise of PCB-layer capacitors?  Its not jumping out at me...

Comment: No I meant for spiral conductor and microstrip  losses.  Caps are OEM specific for RMS current or ESR max and   Or DF value

Comment: I posted a more specific question here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/568212/256265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you will need to (a) simulate the filter with an EM simulator, to see where the currents in the copper are largest (often at the corners of the traces) or better yet (b) build the filter and measure the temperature rise when it’s used at high power. A multi physics type of simulation would find the current maximums and estimate the temperature rise at the same time.

Comment: It seems that there must be a way to calculate ESR at a given frequency for two plates separated with a dielectric of a known Er without EM simulation...I'm willing to be wrong here but if we can get ESR then I can calculate wattage and heat dissipation.

Comment: For the capacitor structure, You can probably get an idea. Use the dissipation factor of the pcb material and the capacitive reactance at the frequency of interest to calculate ESR. 

For the inductive parts, and conductor losses,  you could use resistance of the copper and lumped element currents to calculate losses.  

But these are low frequency approaches that neglect skin effect and frequency dependent dielectric losses.  I think you will end up with numbers that don’t relate to reality.