# What high-power anti-reflection mechanisms exist to protect amplifiers when an the antenna is disconnected?

Tags: power, amplifier, rf, heat

To avoid overheating front-end components by reflection from high-power amplifiers, how can you protect against user error when the amp turns on but the antenna is disconnected?

I already know about circulators with a big dummy load, but what smaller or smarter options are available that could be designed onto a PCB?

(In this case, we are designing for 300W at 144MHz and 440MHz.)

Comment: https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/test-methods/rf-microwave-power-meter/inline-wattmeter.php

Answer (score 2):

If you use Saturn’s PCB software to choose a transmission line so it raises track temp. Say a  20’C rise above ambient by thickness and width for the impedance you want with coplanar  gnd a track and a ground plane for low emissions reflected into an open circuit with impedances matched by electrical test.

Then design a track for -40dB crosstalk, you have a DC40 into a Schottky diode.

This can be used to regulate or disable the output.

Comment: Wow that sounds neat, but I think I need more explanation in the first paragraph.  Are you saying I can reduce the reflection by -40dB with some feedline-length magic and a diode?

Comment: The crosstalk reflected becomes the directional coupler in strip line. I used a DIY one to tune a transmitter antenna despun dipole length for BB VI Tx by minimizing diode voltage (Return Loss) back in the 70’s. Saturn software computes the crosstalk at f , gap, DK and length.. But I have not built anything lately.

Comment: To the OP: I believe he is telling you how to build an inline directional coupler onto your PCB. It will give you a DC output proportional to reflected power. Take a look at the link in my comment.